# Can I dualboot Ubuntu and MacOS by using Bootcamp?

Tags: dual-boot, macosx, bootcamp

I was wondering, can I dual boot Ubuntu and MacOS using Bootcamp? Like can I, once I download Windows 10, replace it with Ubuntu? Because Bootcamp creates a partition on the MacOS disk to install Windows 10, right? So is it possible to replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu on that partition?

Comment: While I don't know the answser to your question for Intel Macs, Ubuntu does not natively support ARM Macs yet. See https://asahilinux.org/